# Moving from first to last in an array when last can be smaller than the first

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, deque

Is there a better way to accomplish moving from first to last in an array when last can be smaller than the first, in Java? This is what I am currently using in my deque implementation:

```
public void printDeque() {
    int start = nextFirst + 1, end = nextLast - 1;
    if (start >= end) {
        for (int i = start; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create an `ArrayList` instance, append each item from `nextFirst` to `nextLast` (modulo the size) and display the resulting list :

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    static String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
    
    public static void deque(int nextFirst, int nextLast) {
        nextFirst %= array.length; // Simple security measure
        nextLast %= array.length; // Simple security measure
        
        int id = nextFirst;
        if (nextLast < nextFirst)
            nextLast += array.length;
        
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (id <= nextLast)
            list.add(array[id++ % array.length]);
        
        String[] result = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        System.out.println(String.join(" ", result));
    }
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        deque(7, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that during traveral, lastIndex does not matter as objects are placed consecutively so we can start at the first position and continue till we encounter a null.

Then we can start at 0 and continue till we get null while remaining less than the first position. This case arises only when first > last.

Here's the code:

```java
private int getFirstIndex() {
    int first = nextFirst + 1;
    if (first == items.length) {
        first = 0;
    }
    return first;
}

public void printDeque() {
    int firstIndex = getFirstIndex()
    for (int i = firstIndex; i < items.length && items[i] != null; i++) {
        System.out.print(items[i] + " ");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < firstIndex && items[i] != null; i++) {
        System.out.print(items[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```